# no method error for nginx chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to use the recipe for Nginx from the Chef opscode website, http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx

When I run the recipe, it's triggering a no method error that traces back to this line  of code from source.rb. This is line 28 referred to in the trace.

```
nginx_url = node['nginx']['source']['url'] ||
  "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}.tar.gz"
```

Can anyone explain what the problem might be? I'm following along with this Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/339-chef-solo-basics?view=asciicast where the recipe (an older version obviously) is working for Ryan.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/var/chef/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/source.rb:28:in `from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:346:in `load_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:151:in `load_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:132:in `block in include_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:131:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:131:in `include_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/dsl/include_recipe.rb:26:in `include_recipe'
/var/chef/cookbooks/main/recipes/default.rb:4:in `from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:346:in `load_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:151:in `load_recipe'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:139:in `block in compile_recipes'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:137:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:137:in `compile_recipes'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:74:in `compile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:86:in `load'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/client.rb:224:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/client.rb:467:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/client.rb:200:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application.rb:190:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:239:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:231:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:231:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/application.rb:73:in `run'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about being late to the party. In case you didn't solve this before you need to enter it as a dependency in `metadata.rb`

Like below:

```
name             'casino-saga'
maintainer       'Mikael Henriksson'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures casino-saga servers'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'

depends 'apt'
depends 'build-essential'
depends 'ohai'
depends 'runit'
depends 'nginx'
depends 'rbenv'
depends 'postgresql'
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `node`, `node['nginx']`, or `node['nginx']['source']` is `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm a bit late, but I've solved the problem by downloading the [ohai](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ohai) cookbook and adding it to my Vagrantfile.

(Yes, I'm using Chef through Vagrant)